# Duda sobre mi javascript enlazado con html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5

Buenas a todos,

Estoy intentando hacer un menú el cual al clickar la etiqueta "label" cambie el src de la imagen por otro a modo de "hacer check", me explico:
Mi intención es que al hacer click se me ilumine el icono, y al volver a clickar el icono, se me ponga mas grisáceo (tengo dichos iconos en imagenes las dos versiones) y solo consigo que se ilumine pero no vuelve al estado anterior.

```js
function Cambio(){
    var id = document.getElementById().getAttribute('id');
    
    
    switch(id){
    case id == "imgJuegos":
    
    if (document.getElementById('imgJuegos').src == 'img/juegos.png'){
    document.getElementById('imgJuegos').src ='img/bjuegos.png';
      }
    
    if (document.getElementById('imgJuegos').src == 'img/bjuegos.png'){
    document.getElementById('imgJuegos').src ='img/juegos.png';
      }
    }
```

```html
<label class="label-checkbox item-content obicus" style="margin-left:25%;" onclick="Cambio();">
<input type="checkbox" name="ks-radio" value="Books" >
<div class="item-media">
          <img style="height:24px; width:24px;" id="imgDj" src="img/bdj.png" >
        </div>

<div class="item-inner">
<div class="item-title"></div>
</div>
</label>
```

Comment: Has probado poniendo un "else if" asi no te haria las dos comprobaciones

Comment: De todas maneras este código no esta completo ni correctamente escrito.

Comment: Buenas, gracias a por comentar, intenté poner else if y lo mismo, y GDP...podrías indicarme que está mal escrito? Soy un noob del javascript jeje

Comment: Desde luego, pero es que lo que esta mal desde luego es ese doble if, por que cambia la imagen de una a otra y en segundo DE NUEVO la vuelve a reponer, por eso siempre le sale la misma imagen, deberia comprobar si es una u otra, para eso el "else if"

Comment: No se supone Diego Anton que le digo "si es juegos cambiate a bjuegos y viceversa"? Perdón por mi ignorancia :D p.d. Acabo de observar lo que me has dicho, pero con else if se me queda igual :/

Comment: La pregunta necesita un poco de formato, pero no tengo permisos para ello

Comment: @J.Gone tu aqui lo que le estas diciendo es que si la id es imgJuegos pille la imagen y compruebe si tiene esa url. Si es A la cambia por B... PERO! seguido vuelves a comprobar y pasas otra vez de B a A :S... De todas formas no trabajes con ifs dentro de un switch, para eso tienes los case. Cada cosa para lo que es.

Answer (score 0):

Juega con las clases.
En mi caso si es si, cambio a no y le modifico el src.
Si es no cambio a si y lo mismo, modifico el src.

Recuerda borrar la clase antes de añadir otra, o tendras las dos.

```js
$("#imagen").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass( "no" );
    $(".si").attr("src","http://www.i2clipart.com/cliparts/9/3/a/f/clipart-green-tick-93af.png"); 
    $(".no").attr("src","http://www.i2clipart.com/cliparts/8/9/e/0/clipart-red-cross-89e0.png");    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.i2clipart.com/cliparts/9/3/a/f/clipart-green-tick-93af.png" id="imagen" class="si">
```

Comment: Gracias! Ahora voy a echarle un ojo a ver si me funciona, que vi que a ti te funciona :)

Comment: @GDP Si se acepta usar jQuery, podrías usar [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/), que simplifica mucho el código

Comment: @PabloLozano cierto, pero he intentado mantener un "poco" el formato de su código, y tiene un switch.

Comment: @GDP que es un poco innecesario, si le ayudamos a hacer el código más limpio, matamos dos pájaros de un tiro

Comment: @PabloLozano bien, cambio ;P

Answer (score 0):

*Pues, ahí te hago un efecto con un div, tiene comentarios de lo que voy haciendo en el mismo código para que lo entiendas,ya que veo que te gustan los efectos, usando solo **Javacript***

```js
/* Imágenes */
var imagenes = {
  imagen1: "https://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/universosteven/images/4/4b/Circular_Quartz_Fusion_Gem-0.png/revision/latest?cb=20160815020913&path-prefix=es",
  imagen2: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRwg3PByXSW9HXmU8u8wwt_uNS5gYsuvuOvXrnyta8OqGo39N7O"
};
/* Elementos necesarios */

/* Div */ var div = document.getElementById("cambiame");
/* Elemento IMG */ var mg = document.getElementById("imgg");

/* Evento al pasar mouse encima */
div.addEventListener("mouseover",cambiar); /* Al pasar el mouse por encima ejecuta la función cambiar */
div.addEventListener("mouseleave",original) /* Al sacar el mouse de encima ejecuta la función original */
function cambiar(){
  mg.src = imagenes.imagen1;
  mg.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 40px 6px yellow"; // Color
  mg.style.transform = "scale(1.2)"; // Efecto agrandar
  mg.style.transition = "all 2s"; // Cuanto demorará en agrandar
}
function original(){
  mg.src = imagenes.imagen2; // Esta imagén es la original y al sacar el mouse de encima del div, vuelve el fondo a esta imágen.
  mg.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px 0px dimgray"; // Saco color
  mg.style.transform = "scale(1)"; // Volver tamaño original
  mg.style.transition = "all 2s"; // Cuanto demorará en volver al tamaño
}
```

```css
#cambiame{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border-radius:150px;
  position:absolute;
  top:20%;
  left:20%;
  background-color:dimgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cambiame">
    <img width="100%" height="100%" style="border-radius:150px;" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRwg3PByXSW9HXmU8u8wwt_uNS5gYsuvuOvXrnyta8OqGo39N7O" id="imgg"/>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias !

Comment: De nada @J.Gone, fuí más ignorante que ahora y recibí bastante ayuda de esta comunidad, ayudarse entre todos es lo mejor!!